# Capturing matches with sed

Tags: sed

I have just started experimenting with sed and don't really get how does match capturing work: if I have a code like this for capturing two words `sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*\([a-z]*\).*/\1 \2/'` why isn't the second word captured?

Edit1: Let's say I have this string: "the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". I want sed to match "the brown", but it only matches the first word

Comment: Give us the string (or) input file for which the above `sed` command did not work

Comment: `*` is greedy.. it will try to match as much as possible.. and while whole expression has to be matched, preference is for expressions to left to match first... and as `*` means zero or more matching, it is perfectly okay for `.*` or `[a-z]*` to be empty

Comment: replace the dot in `.*` with space character... `sed 's/\([a-z]*\) *\([a-z]*\).*/\1 \2/'`

Comment: Thank you Sundeep, got it working!

Comment: If you use `+` instead of `*` it will require "at least one", instead of "zero or more". That could be useful for you, too. It is better to wirte regular expressions so that for any text you want to match, there is only one way of matching it. Do not let sed guess how you want to match, or it gets slow: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/977/backtracking/3180/why-can-backtracking-be-a-trap#t=201608191201561588455

Comment: @Yunnosch isn't that a GNU extension or something?  I don't think that is standard POSIX.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah Possible, I admit, because my experience is with gnu sed. (e.g. GNU sed version 4.2.1). It definitly only works with "-E" or "-r". Good point, thanks. However, the warning about catastrophic backtracking stands. Replace `pattern+` by `pattern(pattern)*` does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Quoting Sundeep, just to make a Q/A pair.)

replace the dot in `.*` with space character...

```
sed 's/\([a-z]*\) *\([a-z]*\).*/\1 \2/'
```

Comment: For better backtracking safety, use ` {1,}` instead of ` *`. I hope that is no extension.